# Keep material strength while scaling

Tags: edit-mode, proportional-editing

I'm having a little trouble with something.

I have let's say a hollowed cylinder (or pipe) with an outer diameter of 50mm and an inner diameter of 40mm. So the wall strength is about 5mm. If i scale up the diameter (x+y), it also scales up the wall strength. Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: Hello, what "strength" are your referring to?

Comment: i am pretty sure he means the wall thickness

Comment: Oh OK so he could also use a Solidify modifier I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't mind using geometry nodes, you could use this node setup:

[image]

to get this:

[image]

i think an even better solution is this (because of much better performance):

[image]